# builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 17: invalid continuation byte

Tags: encoding, python-3.x, utf-8

(WingIDE with python 3.3.0)

i write a very simpe python source file test.py,there are only two lines in the file

```
print('123')
#因为是灰度图所以shape(im)返回二元组,彩色图则返回三元组
```

the second line is Chinese annotation, when i run this file,it shows excepton as follow:
builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 17: invalid continuation byte

when I delete the second line, it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default encoding for source files is UTF-8. For everything else, there's [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

```
#!/usr/python
# -*- coding: gb2312 -*-

print('123')
#因为是灰度图所以shape(im)返回二元组,彩色图则返回三元组
```

Comment: Thank you ,@lgnacio, I add a line at the benginning of the file :# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

Comment: @tenos: ... Did you read the error message? *It's not UTF-8.*

Comment: I don't know why specifying UTF-8 would work; I suspect a bug.